# Need to append a subdirectory before "/static" in development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

Apparently the solutions I keep coming across are meant for production and not development, thus they are not working.

These solutions include any number of the following:

**index.html**

```
<base href="/client">
```

**.env**

```
PUBLIC_URL="/client"
```

**package.json**

```
"homepage": "/client"

or 

"homepage: "http://localhost/client"
```

**App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter
  basename='/client'>
  <>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Test} />
  </>
</BrowserRouter>
```

None of these work in solving what I am trying to accomplish: I need the URL for assets to be `/client/static` and not `/static`. The latter makes the app not render at all in my development environment.

I'm basically playing around in development at this point and routing should be like the following:

```
/       = general landing page
/client = route for client login
/admin  = route for internal admin login
/api    = route for server that the /client and /admin communicate with
```

Seems like something that should be fairly easy to implement, but failing at it as none of the proposed solutions seem to work in development. For example, `PUBLIC_URL` is ignored in development according to the Node and/or React docs.

What is the solution here?

Repo to demo the issue:

https://github.com/eox-dev/subdir-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible currently in CRA:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8222#issuecomment-568308139